# Is 綴飾 being used naturally as a verb in 這件衣服綴飾了許多亮片?

Tags: usage, word

Is the following sentence natural for native speakers of Mandarin?

> 這件衣服**綴飾**了許多亮片，適合在晚宴上穿著。

Is "綴飾" used naturally? I thought it's supposed to be used as a noun.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a natural usage. In fact, I would even say that 綴飾 as a noun is derivative of its verbal usage, considering that it is a compound of two verbs. An analogous case could be 收藏, which is both a verb meaning "to collect", as well as a noun meaning "collection (that which is collected)".

Comment: But I cannot seem to find any real-life examples of its verbal use on Google.

Comment: I imagine that's because this word is used a lot in online store listings? It's hard to filter out those results, but I found these two sentence at least: "王后的五种车：一是重翟，驾车的马面上有用金镂饰的当卢，马勒两侧缀饰着红色的缯带。" "金齐国王墓中齐国王夫人头戴的蹋鸱巾和齐国王的相似，头巾下有一顶用铁丝编制的盛子做支撑，头巾背后中部缀饰了一件双练鹊衔花枝玉饰。"

Comment: In any case it is not a very common word. Quite literary, in fact. You might have better luck finding real usage in a sentence if you search in Google Books.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I don't find all verbal instaces of "綴飾" odd. This one, "牆上掛的畫總覺得很有藝術感，綴飾了整片水泥牆" seems natural to me, as it fits the pattern "(點)綴(裝)飾 something," i.e., "to decorate something."

Answer (score 1):

綴飾 can either be used as a verb as "decorate", or a noun as "decoration". For the given sentence, 這件衣服綴飾了許多亮片 - This cloth is/has **decorated** with many paillettes. Here, 綴 means 縫補(sew) or 連結(connect), both are verbs.

EXample for 綴飾 used as a noun:

- 這件衣服用許多亮片作為綴飾 - This cloth has many paillettes as **decoration**. Here, 綴飾 is clearly a noun.

Answer (score 1):

**缀饰**是点缀装饰的意思。

這件衣服**綴飾了**許多亮片，
This outfit is **decorated** with hundreds of sequins,
適合在晚宴上穿著。
(it is) suitable for wearing to an evening reception.

连衣裙上缀满了数以千计的闪光装饰片。
(The) frocks were stitched full with thousands of sparkling sequins.

(“sequin” was apparently originally the name of a gold coin of the Venetian Republic, also the name of a Turkish gold coin. Women of the Levant apparently wore them as decoration, earrings or necklaces)